# Is it possible to start scrollView pan gesture on a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a hierarchy like so

```
- UIView 
   - UITableView
   - UIButton
```

By default swiping from a UIButton does not scroll the scroll view.  I want to change this so it does.

I could do this by changing the `UIButton` to a `UILabel` and add a `UITapGestureRecogniser` to it to effectively make a custom button.

Is there a way to do it keeping it as a UIButton?

[image]

Comment: what is the hierarchy of the button? Is it a subview of the cell? the ui table view? the navigation bar?

Comment: @YuchenZhong - The button is the sibling of the tableView.  Ill add to my question.

Comment: We have a very similar problem recently. We have a map view (scroll view) and a `UIbutton`. We want to let user pan the map start from the button and make the button only response to the `TouchUpInside` event. However, it seems that using `UITapGestureRecogniser` is the only way of making this possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)moveUpView
  {  
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:n inSection:0];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                animated:YES];
        }
```

Hope this may work

Comment: I have tested on this on my View that was simple View like Signup Screen, have not tested on Tableview. Tell me if it works for tableview as well..!

Comment: Won't this just move the UITableView up? Wouldn't you want to modify the contentOffset instead of the view's frame?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, Are you actually Scrolling Button to scroll the Tableview??

Comment: Hi magid.  Thanks for the answer but this is not what I was after.  I want the scrollview to work normally, but its pan gesture does not work when it is started at the button.

Answer (score 0):

Create a duplicate `UITableView` (with the same `dataSource` and `delegate`), but don't insert it anywhere into the view hierarchy; just add its `panGestureRecognizer` to the `UIButton`. Implement its delegate `-scrollViewDidScroll:` method to set the original `UITableView`'s `contentOffset` to that of the duplicate `UITableView`.